Understanding reason for error message while attempting to install postgresql on a system that already has postgresql installed
Received the following error while attempting to install postgres 14 on Ubuntu 22.04 (expanded output at end of post):
update-alternatives: error: alternative postmaster.1.gz can’t be master: it is a slave of psql.1.gz

I do have postgres 14 and 15 installed on this machine. The issue seems to be related to the symlinks in /etc/alternatives. The corresponding records from the error message are:
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    49 Jul 18 15:10 postmaster.1.gz -> /usr/share/postgresql/15/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    43 Jul 18 15:10 psql.1.gz -> /usr/share/postgresql/15/man/man1/psql.1.gz

It seems to me that the issue is that my alternatives are aliases of postgres 15 processes, so something about the postgres 14 install is running foul of the update-alternatives link groups.
What specifically is the postgres 14 install trying to do here when I get the error alternative postmaster.1.gz can’t be master: it is a slave of psql.1.gz?
Full error output:
(Reading database ... 355540 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack postgresql-14_14.10-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-14 (14.10-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (14.10-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up postgresql-14 (14.10-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
update-alternatives: error: alternative postmaster.1.gz can’t be master: it is a slave of psql.1.gz
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-14 (--install):
 installed postgresql-14 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for postgresql-common (238) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
  en_us
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-14

